ODOO 13 mass mailing external links in email body are getting changed
i am using odoo 13 email marketing on my localhost
when I test, email links work as expected
but when email is sent to subscribers, links in email body are getting changed to something like http://localhost:8069/r/dYf/m/
how can I avoid this?
Please advise
i have tried almost everything
